# Permutations on $[2n]$ with relative ($\!\!\bmod n$) restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question:** Let $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$ be the permutations on $[2n]=\{1,2,\ldots, 2n\}$. Let $$\mathcal{J}_n=\{\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_{2n} \mid \sigma(i) \not\equiv \sigma(i+n)\mod n, \text{ for all $i\in [n]$}\}.$$

Prove that $$|\mathcal{J}_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-2)^k(n!)^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

**Approach:** I believe that this problem can be solved with rook polynomials. The issue I am having is that in all the examples I've seen, the restrictions for the permutations are of the form $\sigma(i)\neq j$. In such cases, determining the board for which to compute the rook polynomial on is straightforward. However, in this problem the restrictions are relative i.e. of the form $\sigma(i)\not\equiv \sigma(i+n)\bmod n$ and so I'm not sure what the correct board is going to be? I would naively think that the board should be $2n\times 2n$, and we place the restrictions on $(i,i+n\bmod n)$ but the summation in the final formula seems to suggest an $n\times n$ board. Any advice or alternate approaches would be appreciated, perhaps i'm missing a straightforward exponential generating function approach.

**Second Approach:** As mentioned in the comments, the relative positions perhaps make the rook polynomial approach ineffective, as suggested inclusion/exclusion should be the right tool. With this in mind we remark that we can suggestively rewrite the solution as $$|\mathcal{J}_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(2^kn!(2(n-k))!\right),$$ and interpreting $2^kn!(2(n-k))!$ as the number of permutations with *at least* some set of properties then the answer would be the number of permutation with none of the properties... would the $i$th property be $\sigma(i)\equiv \sigma(i+n)\mod n$?

Comment: I don't think rooks polynomials will work.  As you say rook polynomials are useful for permutations with restrictions on absolute positions, but here we have restrictions on relative positions.  What first occurs to me is inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: yeah this might work, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a missing exponent in the denominator: the $(n-k)!$ ought to be squared.

For $k\in[n]$ let $A_k$ be the set of permutations $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(k)\equiv\sigma(k+n)\pmod n$. There are $2n$ choices for $\langle\sigma(k),\sigma(k+n)\rangle$ and $(2n-2)!$ permutations of the remaining $2n-2$ members of $[2n]$, so $|A_k|=2n(2n-2)!$. If $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]$, and $|I|=k$, then

$$\left|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right|=2^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(2n-2k)!\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}2^k\binom{n}k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(2n-2k)!\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}2^k\frac{n!^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!^2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the number of good permutations is

$$\begin{align*}
(2n)!-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}2^k\frac{n!^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!^2}&=(2n)!+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k2^k\frac{n!^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k2^k\frac{n!^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-2)^kn!^2(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!^2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on your calculation of $|\cap_{i=1}^n A_i|$? is there not $n!$ ways to order the pairs ($\sigma(i)=\sigma(i+n)$)? Why is there an $(n-k)!$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Connor: For each $i\in I$ we need to choose a $k\in[n]$ and whether to assign it to $\sigma(i)$ or to $\sigma(i+n)$; $k+n$ will then be assigned to $\sigma(i+n)$ or to $\sigma(i)$, respectively. There are $\binom{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways to make those assignments, and each can be made in $2$ ways once the $k$s are chosen, so we get a total of $\frac{2^kn!}{(n-k)!}$ possibilities. If you prefer, that $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is $\binom{n}kk!$: choose the $k$ values, then permute them amongst the members of $I$.